# Hiding a SharePoint Web Part from code behind

Tags: web-parts

I wanted to hide a web part when there are no results in that web part.
Could anyone help me how to do this in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript in this fashion perhaps:

http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2008/03/13/free-mosswss-2007-web-part-hide-controls-via-javascript/

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I would try this.
Happy Christmas